# How can I edit the list of cipher suite in Java using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography, bouncycastle

The following code lists the supported cipher suites by Java SE 8:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
public class ListCiphers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(); 
        String[] cipherSuites = factory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cipherSuites));

    } //end main
}
```

I want to make SSL client which is configured with some specific list of cipher suites. The cipher suites I want to use are standardized but not supported by Jva SE 8. For example, this cipher is listed in firefox:

```
ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA
```

Please, help me with any way that allows me to edit the list of cipher suite in my SSL client. Does Bouncy Castle help in this? How? Please, give me clear step by step. Also if you knwo what I want can be achieved by using another language such as python, also please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I edit the list of cipher suite in Java using Bouncy Castle

See [Which Cipher Suites to enable for SSL Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1037590) and use [`SSLSocketFactoryEx`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365536/608639). Its a drop-in replacement for Java's [`SSLSocketFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365536/608639)

If you don't want to use `SSLSocketFactoryEx`, then rip the code to find the intersection of cipher suites.

It controls both protocols and cipher suites. There are no unexpected surprises, like getting a SSLv3 socket back from `SSLSocketFactory.getInstance("TLS");`.

Nothing is configurable, so the user cannot shoot themselves in the foot. It's also ready for TLS 1.3

Answer (score 4):

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA is supported by Java 8 (and 7) without adding BouncyCastle, and it is enabled in JSSE by default so you don't need to "edit" anything. 
But *all* JREs disallow *all* **256-bit** symmetric crypto (including 256-bit SSL/TLS ciphersuites) unless you install the "JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files"; 
see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html under "Additional Resources" near the bottom.

Comment: thanks. I did that & now can get AES_256 support in my client. I mentioned `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA` just as an example, but there are other ciphers that are not included. I did not find any way for adding them till this moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit the cipher suites directly on factory.

However you can choose what exact ciphers to support (from the available) on the `SSLSocket`

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
String[] cipherSuites = factory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket();

// Choose the exact ciphers you need from the available
String[] filteredCipherSuites = cipherSuites; 

sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(filteredCipherSuites);
```